AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'
I make my discord bot, and make the report command on modal.
class ReportModal(discord.ui.Modal, title="Репорт юзер"):
    user_name = discord.ui.TextInput(label="Юзер дискорд наме", placeholder="eg. Jgfhfhjfkfk#0000", required=True, max_length=10000, style=discord.TextStyle.short)
    user_id = discord.ui.TextInput(label="Юзер дискорд наме2", placeholder="eg. Jgfhfhjfkfk#0000", required=True, max_length=10000, style=discord.TextStyle.long)
@bot.command(name="report", description="Репорт юзер")#name="report", description="Репорт юзер"
async def report(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    modal = ReportModal()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)

Error
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 26, in report
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'


I have fixed the code and error formatting for you. Please read the formatting help for details.

You are mixing the "classic commands" with the new "app commands" (slash commands).
Try using @bot.tree.command instead of @bot.command.
Don't forget to sync your commands using await bot.tree.sync()!

The old commands get a Context object as the first argument. The new app commands get an Interaction object.
You can find a working example using the new commands here.
